# How to get the 'variable' line from file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

This is my script. It print every row in the file with the number of row.
Next i want to read which row user choosed and save it to some variable.

```
  I=1
    for ROW in $(cat file.txt)
    do
        echo "$I $ROW"
        I=`expr $I + 1`
    done
    read var
    awk 'FNR = $var {print}' file.txt
```

Then i want to to print / save the chosen row into the file.

How can I do this ?

when i `echo $var` it shows me properly the number. But when i'm trying to use this variable in awk, it print every line.

How to read the 'var' line from file?

And moreover, how to save this line in other variable?

Example file.txt

```
1 line1
2 line2
3 line3
4 line4
```

when i tap 3 i want to read third line from file.

Comment: Never do this: `for x in $(command)` or \`command\` or $var. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. "${names[@]}") or a while-read 
                loop (eg. while read -r line). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat -n file.txt; read var; line="$(sed -n ${var}p file)"; echo "$line"
```

With more focus on Dryingsoussage's version:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="file.txt"
declare -i counter=0   # set integer attribute
var=0

while read -r line; do
  counter=counter+1
  printf "%d %s\n" "$counter" "$line"
done < "$file"

# check for number and greater-than 0 and less-than-or-equal $counter
until [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ $var -gt 0 ]] && [[ $var -le $counter ]]; do
  read -p "Enter line number:" var
done

awk -v var="$var" 'FNR==var {print}' "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what i want to get :)

Comment: +1 for `cat -n`. But this doesn't check that `var` is non-empty/non-evil/otherwise valid before using it unquoted in a shell command.

Comment: @EtanReisner: okay :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Cyrus I would change `[[ $var -gt 0 ]]` and `[[ $var -le $counter ]]` to `(( var > 0 && var <= counter ))`. It is also possible to change `counter=counter+1` to `(( ++counter ))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $varname inside ' ' they will not be resolved.

look at this other post it should help you:
[How to use shell variables in an awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Answer (score 0):

First: You cannot use `$var` in a single quotes, as echo '$var' would be plain $var, no its value.
Second: You used `=` (assignment) operator instead of `==` (equality) operator.
Third: You don't have to write `{ print }` if you want the line to be printed. You can write nothing instead.
Fourth: As was explained in the deleted comment below - do not allow bash expanding the variables in the awk script code, as it can lead to code injection.
So conclusion is:

```
awk -v var="$var" 'FNR == var' file.txt
```

should do what you want.

Comment: @EdMorton: I see your point. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat -n file.txt
read var
row="$(awk -v tgt="$var" 'NR==tgt{print;exit}' file.txt)"
```

Comment: This has shown up in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, even though it's not - maybe triggered by code-only?

Comment: I'll approve it, but perhaps the author might want to add some explanation.

Comment: There's nothing to explain, it just is what it says it is.... Not all answers require additional text and IMHO the simpler ones are better without it so the reader who doesn't understand it has to go look up a couple of simple constructs and learns more from that than being spoon-fed.